# Python: RuntimeError: ecCodes library not found using ['eccodes', 'libeccodes.so', 'libeccodes'] after installing cfgrib

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed `cfgrib` on my macOs by doing the following

```
python3.8 -m pip install cfgrib
```

Now if I open try to import `cfgrib`

```
import cfgrib
```

I get

```
RuntimeError: ecCodes library not found using ['eccodes', 'libeccodes.so', 'libeccodes']
```

I solved it by installing `cfgrib` via homebrew.

```
brew install eccodes
```

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was:

```
pip install ecmwflibs
import ecmwflibs
pip install cfgrib
import cfgrib
```

Comment: not sure who downvoted you - this actually worked

Answer (score 2):

The package `cfgrib` depends on the eccodes python package to access the ECMWF ecCodes binary library.
So install:

```
pip install eccodes
```

After that you can try:

```
python -m cfgrib selfcheck
```

You should get an output like this:

```
Found: ecCodes v2.20.0.
Your system is ready.
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

If not, maybe you have to install the packages that are listen in your error message.

Comment: it does not work, I still get the same error if do this`python -m cfgrib selfcheck` after installing `eccodes`

Comment: @emax  What message comes when you type `python -m cfgrib selfcheck`?

Comment: ```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/felix/repo/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cfgrib/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
...
  File "/home/felix/repo/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gribapi/gribapi.py", line 2228, in <module>
    __version__ = grib_get_api_version()
  File "/home/felix/repo/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gribapi/gribapi.py", line 2218, in grib_get_api_version
    raise RuntimeError("Could not load the ecCodes library!")
RuntimeError: Could not load the ecCodes library!
```

Comment: @emax use ```!python -m cfgrib selfcheck```